# add button easyAdmin symfony 6 has no effect

Tags: symfony, easyadmin

I am new to symfony. I installed easyAdmin bundle. It works till I click on 'add' button. On my local machine, it redirects correctly to the form page but on server, it has no effect.
I don't know where to look. Any help would be awesome.

http://ippp.ninapresotto.com/admin

I installed symfony/apache-pack that creates a .htaccess in /public , could it be the reason ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The page is accessible by manually altering the action in URL (added a new theme), do you have some script acting on the button?

Comment: Thanks for looking..i have no script that would change the action.

Comment: How did you manually do it ?

Comment: From your link, after the page loads, edit the URL changing to https://ippp.ninapresotto.com/admin?crudAction=new&crudControllerFqcn=App%5CController%5CAdmin%5CThemeCrudController

Comment: Yes ok. So the href on the button should be this one. Do you have an idea why it's not the case ?

Comment: The href has a `referrer` parameter (only difference) so that must be triggering the redirect to `index`, review your controller action for how that's handled.

Comment: I looked through what I could see through the profiler and I think maybe it has to with the `BeforeCrudActionEvent` I'm not really sure, I've used Sonata Admin but never EasyAdmin sorry. If you add more details to the question I'll up-vote and hopefully draw more attention from someone who can answer definitively.

Comment: Ok thanks a lot for helping. I am gonna restart from scratch have a look at Sonata :)